# Redefining ordering in index

Tags: indexing, sorting, bibleref

I'm generating an index of Bible references (using the `bibleref`) package. Bible references are usually not sorted by alphabetical order of book, but rather by order of appearance in the Bible (Genesis, Deuteronomy, etc.). The verses inside each chapter should be sorted numerically.

Currently, my index looks like (it's in French):

```
Actes
   1, 20
   1.4, 20
Apocalypse
   3.20, 56
   5, 62
1 Corinthiens
   2.9, 69
Daniel
   12.4, 29
```

Instead, I would like:

```
Daniel
   12.4, 29
Actes
   1, 20
   1.4, 20
1 Corinthiens
   2.9, 69
Apocalypse
   3.20, 56
   5, 62
```

ordered by Bible book as they appear in the Bible. I think `xindy` can do that (and `imakeidx` can use `xindy`). How would I go about doing it?

**Edit:**

The `bibleref` package provides a `\biblerefmap` command to fix the index. This works fine in general, but French Bible book names have accents, and `\biblerefmap` concatenates the book name as found in the index to create a macro name, like:

```
\newcommand*{\biblerefmap}[2]{%
   \expandafter\def\csname @bibleref@map@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}
```

So, this fails because of accents:

```
\biblerefmap{Genèse}{1@Ancien Testament!01}
\biblerefmap{Exode}{1@Ancien Testament!02}
\biblerefmap{Lévitique}{1@Ancien Testament!03}
```

When generating the index, `bibleref` then considers the `\@bibleref@map@bookname` macros and replaces the book name with the contents if they exist. Since the key entry is the full book name as present in the index, I don't see how to not use accentuated characters in French.

Is there a way I could circumvent the accents issue?

Comment: An example of what you are trying to achieve would be welcome.

Comment: @egreg: example added.

Comment: @Raphink Please, add the customization you have up to now, as the default of **bibleref** give different results.

Comment: @egreg: Well, I'm using `bibleref-french`, which might explain.

Comment: @egreg: Actually, I just saw that the `bibleref` package provides a `\biblerefmap` command to order books. I might try that.

Comment: The `\biblerefmap` command does what I want in `bibleref`, but it takes Bible book names and sets aggregates them to generate a macro such as `\@bibleref@map@Genesis`. This does not work for French names, which contain accents. Any idea how to circumvent that?

Comment: @Raphink If I say `\biblerefmap{ICorinthians}{...}`, the entry in the index is correctly **1 Corinthiens**. That is, you must use the English names in `\ibibleverse`. You can also set French symbolic names with `\addbiblebook{1Cor}{1 Corinthiens}`, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I patched the `bibleref` module locally:

```
--- a/bibleref/bibleref.sty
+++ b/bibleref/bibleref.sty
@@ -800,7 +800,7 @@ defined}{}}}
     \PackageError{bibleref}{Unknown book '#1'}{}%
   }%
   {%
-    \@bv@idxsort{\csname br@#1\endcsname}%
+    \@bv@idxsort{#1}%
     \def\@bv@chidxsort{}%
     \BRbooktitlestyle{\csname br@#1\endcsname}%
     \let\@bv@org@bookof\BRbookof
```

This way, it's the abbreviated form that is used for keys, which then allows me to use `\biblerefmap` as:

```
\biblerefmap{Gn}{1@Ancien Testament!01}
\biblerefmap{Ex}{1@Ancien Testament!02}
\biblerefmap{Lv}{1@Ancien Testament!03}
etc.
```

which solves my problem.