# Altering index sort order in bibleref

Tags: indexing, sorting, bibleref

Original post:

The **bibleref** package affords tidy citation and indexing of Bible passages; sort order is by default alphabetical by book. According to the documentation, one can change the to another desired sequence by issuing suitable **\biblerefmap** commands for each book.

However, having tried various scenarious, this appears to work for the default citation style, but not when an alternate built-in style is invoked, whether by package option or by issuing **\biblerefstyle**. Also, an attempt to get around the problem using **\setbooktitle** and **\setindexbooktitle** causes the desired sort order to be ignored as well. Here's my minimal example:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatexmk
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{bibleref}
% Replacing the previous line with the following causes the sort to revert to alphabetical
%\usepackage[jerusalem]{bibleref}
% Adding the next line after the \usepackage does the same.
%\biblerefstyle{jerusalem}
\biblerefmap{Genesis}{01}
\biblerefmap{Exodus}{02}
\biblerefmap{Leviticus}{03}
\biblerefmap{Numbers}{04}
\biblerefmap{Deuteronomy}{05}
\biblerefmap{Joshua}{06}
\biblerefmap{Judges}{07}
\biblerefmap{1Samuel}{08}
\biblerefmap{2Samuel}{09}
\biblerefmap{1Kings}{10}
\biblerefmap{2Kings}{11}
\biblerefmap{Isaiah}{12}
\biblerefmap{Jeremiah}{13}
\biblerefmap{Ezekiel}{14}
\biblerefmap{Hosea}{15}
\biblerefmap{Joel}{16}
\biblerefmap{Amos}{17}
\biblerefmap{Obadiah}{18}
\biblerefmap{Jonah}{19}
\biblerefmap{Micah}{20}
\biblerefmap{Nahum}{21}
\biblerefmap{Habbakuk}{22}
\biblerefmap{Zephaniah}{23}
\biblerefmap{Haggai}{24}
\biblerefmap{Zecharaiah}{25}
\biblerefmap{Malachi}{26}
\biblerefmap{Psalms}{27}
\biblerefmap{Job}{28}
\biblerefmap{Proverbs}{29}
\biblerefmap{Ruth}{30}
\biblerefmap{Song of Songs}{31}
\biblerefmap{Ecclesiastes}{32}
\biblerefmap{Lamentations}{33}
\biblerefmap{Esther}{34}
\biblerefmap{Daniel}{35}
\biblerefmap{Ezra}{36}
\biblerefmap{Nehemiah}{37}
\biblerefmap{1Chronicles}{38}
\biblerefmap{2Chronicles}{39}
% Need the Bible citations in a separate index
\renewcommand{\biblerefindex}{\index[biblecites]}
\makeindex[biblecites]

\begin{document}
Dummy text citing \ibibleverse{Genesis}(1:1) and \ibibleverse{Exodus}(10:11-20).
\printindex[biblecites]
\end{document}
```

BTW, XeLaTeX is used here because in my actual project, I use Hebrew text. However, regular LaTeX doesn't seem to offer any improvement. Neither does using regular **\makeindex** and **\printindex**.

Can anyone advise on a solution?

Update (13 August):

I'd seen a change proposed to **bibleref** [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19277/redefining-ordering-in-index) but it didn't at first seem relevant. Nevertheless, I decided to try it... and it seemed to solve my problem. Further testing suggested this worked for the various predefined styles.

BUT--when I recompiled my actual project, the order remained unchanged! I brought it back down to the minimal example, step by step, and it still didn't work. I finally discovered that in the MWE, I had used

```
\ibibleverse{Genesis}(1:1)
```

whereas in my actual project, I had

```
\ibibleverse{Gn}(1:1)
```

etc. In other words, the patch alluded to above seems to work, so long as actual citations use the full rather than abbreviated forms of books.

Consequently, I view this as an interim solution only.

Update (10 September):

As it happens, the original author of **bibleref** is no longer supporting this package; maintenance has passed to the authors of **biblref-mouth** and **bibleref-parse**, who are aiming to merge the three packages (http://www.dickimaw-books.com/notlisted.html).

However, I understand from communicating briefly with them that progress at the moment is quite slow; therefore users should be prepared to use **bibleref** as is for the time being.