# Russian for bibleref

Tags: indexing, languages, xindy, russian

I am trying to use `bibleref` for Russian book, and I want to have short references like `1 Кор. 13:1-3` inside the main text, and one separate index of bible references that will be sorted accoridng to the order in the Bible and will have references like

```
Первое послание к Коринфянам
    13:1-3  . . . . . .  100
```

The global scheme is that I

1. patched `bibleref.sty`
2. redefined `\setbooktitle`, `\setbookindextitle` 
   and defined some other stuff to work with Russian Bible book names.
3. every run I do some cleanup in the `.idx` file

I am sure that points 1 and 3 are not-good-LaTeX-style, and I will be grateful for an advice about how to do it in a good way.

Well, here are the details, sorry for a lot of text.

But I hope that it might be useful for somebody.

[image: Final result]

### Patching `bibleref.sty`

The idea is [from here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19287/34311), and it helped me with all other stuff.

I changed the line 803 from

```
\@bv@idxsort{\csname br@#1\endcsname}%
```

to

```
\@bv@idxsort{#1}%
```

### Introducing Russian book names

I wrote a long file with definitions.

First I introduce my command to deal with Bible references, it is called `\Bref`, and uses one parameter.

```
\makeatletter
\protected\def\Bref#1{\xBref{}#1 \relax}
\def\xBref#1#2 #3{%
\ifx\relax#3%
\ibibleverse{\@nameuse{\detokenize{#1}}}(#2)% detokenize needed to deal with encoded strings
\expandafter\xthree
\fi
\xBref{#1#2}#3}
\def\xthree#1#2#3{}
\makeatother
```

Then I introduce Russian variants of the short names to use (with and without dot, just in case):

```
\makeatletter
\@namedef{\detokenize{Быт}}{Genesis}
\@namedef{\detokenize{Быт.}}{Genesis}
...
\@namedef{\detokenize{Откр}}{Revelation}
\@namedef{\detokenize{Откр.}}{Revelation}
\makeatother
```

And after that I put short and long names of all Bible books with appropriate sorting order:

```
\setbooktitle{Genesis}{Быт\BRperiod}%
\setbooktitle{Exodus}{Исх\BRperiod}%
\setbooktitle{Leviticus}{Лев\BRperiod}%
...
\setbooktitle{IIIJohn}{\BRbooknumberstyle{3}Ин\BRperiod}%
\setbooktitle{Jude}{Иуд\BRperiod}%
\setbooktitle{Revelation}{Откр\BRperiod}%

\setindexbooktitle{Genesis}{Ветхий Завет!01@Бытие}%
\setindexbooktitle{Exodus}{Ветхий Завет!02@Исход}%
...
\setindexbooktitle{Hebrews}{Новый Завет!26@Послание к Евреям}%
\setindexbooktitle{Revelation}{Новый Завет!27@Откровение Иоанна Богослова}%
```

I use `multind`, so

```
\makeindex{bible}
\renewcommand{\biblerefindex}{\index{bible}}
```

### Cleanup in `.idx`

It's a pity, but my `.idx` file is kind of messy:

```
\indexentry{John\relax \relax @\BRbooktitlestyle {Новый Завет!04@Евангелие от Иоанна}!007:024@\BRchapterstyle {7}\BRchvsep \BRversestyle {24}|textrm}{21}
\indexentry{ICorinthians\relax \relax @\BRbooktitlestyle {Новый Завет!14@Первое послание к Коринфянам}!006:019@\BRchapterstyle {6}\BRchvsep \BRversestyle {19}|textrm}{22}
```

I do not need almost half of that stuff, and it does not let `xindy` work OK.

In addition the path to my working directory contains Russian letters, so I have to copy my `.idx` file to some other place with simpler path. Thus I run such a shell script:

```
sed "s/|textrm//" bible.idx | sed "s/\(\\\indexentry{\).*@\\\BRbooktitlestyle {\([^}]*\)}/\1\2/" > ~/Documents/Tools/xindy/bible.idx
cd ~/Documents/Tools/xindy/
xindy  -M texindy -M page-ranges -L russian -C utf8 -o bible.ind bible.idx
cd -
cp ~/Documents/Tools/xindy/bible.ind bible.ind
```

And what I get is OK for me, but probably there is a much better way to do it. I tried to use `bibleref-mouth` and `bibleref-parse`, but I didn't understand how to make them work with Russian.

P.S. If someone needs full text of commands omitted in (...) above, I can share it.

Comment: Full source is [here](https://github.com/pantlmn/bibleref-rus). If someone could turn it into package or a style for bibleref (and probably include in future LaTeX releases), that would be great.